# VS Code latexmk version mismatch

Tags: latexmk, vscode

I have been trying to install LaTeX in VScode.

I have installed Miktex, perl and the LaTeX Workshop extension latest versions. However, I cannot run the `.tex` file. I am facing a version related error.

```
File::Path version 2.08 required--this is only version 1.08 at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\scripts/latexmk\latexmk.pl line 132.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\scripts/latexmk\latexmk.pl line 132.
latexmk: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.
```

Comment: Maybe update MiKTeX in user and admin mode?

Comment: This error happens because the version of Perl that was used to run latexmk is badly out of date.  It is possible that this is the version of perl that you installed, in which case you should update it.  It is also possible that there is another installation of perl on your computer that is very out-dated.  (This happened to me on a computer where I don't have administrator access.)  Did you have latexmk working previously?

Comment: I have "v5.8.8 built for msys-64int" this perl version installed John. This is out dated? 
I have this Perl only. n No I never used latex neither latexmk.

Comment: Yes, your perl is seriously out of date, more than 14 years old.  Msys's current perl is 5.32.1, if I'm reading its documentation correctly.

Comment: It's Worked !... :D

Answer (score 2):

I have previously installed out-dated perl version. Make sure you have latest perl version(I my case I have install ActivePerl 5.28 now).

You can check your perl version by entering below command in CMD

```
perl -v
```

And make sure you checked to install vscode extension while installing perl.

No need to uninstall previous installed perl just install updated one it will automatically sync in.